# Find the average acceleration

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Find the average acceleration of the tip of the 2.4-cm long hour hand in the interval noon to 6pm.

I found the average velocity is -2.2x10^6 but I'm not sure how to go about finding acceleration. If someone has a few minutes can we chat and you can explain the set up to me?

Comment: Becareful, because velocity and acceleration are vectors and not scalars, so you need to take care of that.

Comment: was my solution for average velocity incorrect?

Comment: What are your units?

Comment: meters per second

Comment: how do I go about finding average acceleration? I know the formula is change in velocity/change in time

Answer (score 0):

Average velocity is displacement over time: in this case, $4.8$ cm in $6$ hours.
That won't help much with computing average acceleration.

Average acceleration is change in velocity over time. The speed of the tip of the hand doesn't
change, but between noon and $6$ pm its direction reverses. So the change in velocity is
equal to twice the speed. Divide by $6$ hours.

Comment: thank you, but I need help finding the average acceleration. I already found the average velocity